# Format date input in view Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date, datetime

I have a dynamic form that recieve data from an array and iterate over it. In case of a date field i want to send in this format into the controller "dd/MM/yyyy" or "dd/MM/yyy hh:mm" tried to use the `ng-bind` but the controller recieves in other format wich is "Wed Dec 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0100 (Local Standard Time)", that should be the format to send via `$http.post` in a service.

Here is my field input

Only date:

```
 <div class="form-field">
                    <label>{{fa.title}}</label>
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" 
                               ng-model="sendForm[fa.name]"
                               placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy"
                               ng-bind="sendForm[fa.name] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

Date and hour:

```
 <div class="form-field">
                    <label>{{fa.title}}</label>
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" 
                               ng-model="sendForm[fa.name]"
                               placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
                               ng-bind="sendForm[fa.name] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

controller.js

```
app.controller("myAppCtrl", ["$scope", "SendForm", "FORMS", function ($scope, SendForm, FORMS) {
   $scope.sendForm = function (form) {
    SendForm.sendInfo(form,
        function onSuccess() {
            $scope.success = true;
        },
        function onError(message) {
            $scope.error = true; 
        },
        function onFinally() {
            $scope.clearForm(form);
        })
}]);
```

service.js

```
app.factory("SendForm", ["$http", "CONFIG", "FORMS","$httpParamSerializer", function ($http, CONFIG, FORMS,$httpParamSerializer) {
return {
    sendInfo: function (form, onSuccess, onError, onFinally, message) {
        var data = {
            absolute: CONFIG.absolute
        };

        for (var i = 0, length = FORMS.form_variables.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(form[FORMS.form_variables[i].name])) {
                var key = FORMS.form_variables[i].name;
                var value = "";
                data[key] = value;
            } else {
                var key = FORMS.form_variables[i].name;
                var value = form[FORMS.form_variables[i].name];
                data[key] = value;
            }
        }
        var config = {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        };

        $http.post(CONFIG.urlSendForm, $httpParamSerializer(data), config).success(function () {
            onSuccess();
            onFinally();

 }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "date" you are using is just a Angualr filter used in UI to return / display the date in correct format. It doesn't change the actual value (simply returns the formatted value).

If you want to get the date as `'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'` in you controller, use it like below -

```
angular.module('myModule')
       .controller('myController', ['$filter',  '$scope', function($filter, $scope) {

       var formattedDate = $filter('date')($scope.sendForm[fa.name], 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm');


}]);
```

Comment: Is to be format in my service before sending via a $post. Ive added now to the question the service and controller, can you adapt you answer, because that way doenst work @Rabi

Answer (score 0):

You need format the date in the controller AND in the service for send this formatted date to server?? which angular version that you used? If you recognize in the service when a value it's a date, you may inject the $filter service in your factory and use it for format the date.

In your Factory

```
app.factory("SendForm", ["$http", "$filter","CONFIG", "FORMS","$httpParamSerializer", function ($http, $filter,CONFIG, FORMS,$httpParamSerializer) {
return {
    sendInfo: function (form, onSuccess, onError, onFinally, message) {
        var data = {
            absolute: CONFIG.absolute
        };
         var dateHourRegex = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}/,
             onlyDateRegex = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/;



        for (var i = 0, length = FORMS.form_variables.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(form[FORMS.form_variables[i].name])) {
                var key = FORMS.form_variables[i].name;
                var value = "";
                data[key] = value;
            } else {
                var key = FORMS.form_variables[i].name;
                var value = form[FORMS.form_variables[i].name];
                if(onlyDateRegex.test(value)){
                   value = dateHourRegex.test(value) ? $filter('date')(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm') 
                                                     : $filter('date')(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                }
                data[key] = value;
            }
        }
        var config = {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        };

        $http.post(CONFIG.urlSendForm, $httpParamSerializer(data), config).success(function () {
            onSuccess();
            onFinally();

 }
}]);
```

Comment: this way to recognize if a value its a date it's not safe,  would be better using regular expressions.

Comment: Yes should be send to the server in that format, the version of angular is v1.4.8. Need to see a way to define if a field is a date in the most dynamic way.